# problem in RVM installation

Tags: rvm

While executing this command to install rvm

```
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

I am getting this error message:

```
mktemp: failed to create file via template ‘/usr/share/rvm/rvm-exec-test.XXXXXX’: Permission denied
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `$` suggests you are attempting this install as a regular (i.e. non-root) user. If so, that is likely your problem, as the `/usr/share/` tree on most Linux operating systems is writable only by root. The software you are trying to install likely wants you to have root permissions to perform the install.

Answer (score 16):

I solved it by changing the following

```
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

into

```
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable
```

The user needs access to the subdir. `/usr/local`

Comment: Note - this version with "sudo" installs it as multi-user in /user/local .  If you want a user-install, where the gems etc go in the user's home-directory, something else is required.  Nevermind that the one that fails (reported by the OP) is what is in the horrible rvm instructions for a single-user install, which have never worked for me without hours of fiddling each and every time.

Answer (score 16):

You probably have (or had) a system-wide installation of RVM. That can be due installing it through a package system like *apt-get* on Ubuntu or *pacman* on Arch Linux (both have rvm packages).

Check your environment variables:

```
> env | grep rvm_path
```

If you have it, then unset it and try to install again:

```
> unset rvm_path
> curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

BEWARE! If you still have rvm installed system-wide, this can give you unpredictable results, make sure you have it uninstalled before doing that.

If you have it already uninstalled and rvm_path is still there, maybe you can log out and log in again to remove them from the environment (or just 
restart the computer).

Comment: thanks working for me, i install ruby previously and also recommend do this <code> unset GEM_HOME</code>

Comment: This solved the problem for me!

Comment: This was helpful, though I also had to run `sudo apt-get purge rvm` per @martincito's answer.  I had installed rvm in multiple ways (apt and manually as multi-user) so i had to manually uninstall too `rvm impolode` (and follow resulting instructions for dirs/files to manually delete).  Only then could I unset some env vars and reinstall as single user

Answer (score 1):

Probably you had install another version of RVM in your computer.
Check, if you have Ubuntu, maybe you installed the exclusive Ubuntu version https://github.com/rvm/ubuntu_rvm
You can uninstall it with command

> sudo apt-get purge rvm

I resolve it like this. And then install rvm with

> \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

And then configuring the source from

> source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm

You then need yo add the source of rvm to your .bashrc and .profile files in your home

Answer (score 1):

I followed these steps and it works for me:

1. Purge all system packages related with ruby or rvm:

```
sudo apt purge ruby rvm
```

2. Make sure that there is not /etc/rvmrc

```
sudo rm -f /etc/rvmrc
```

3. Create .rvm folder on $HOME and install rvm passing some additional arguments like "--ignore-dotfiles" and "--user-install":

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.rvm

curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s -- --ignore-dotfiles --user-install
```

Additional arguments:

--ignore-dotfiles: Avoid the execution of any previous .rvmrc file.

--user-install: The installation will be done in the path $HOME/.rvm

4. Put the following on your ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc file:

```
source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

5. Restart your terminal.

Comment: Welcome to U&L. What "additional arguments" exactly should OP pass to the installer and why exactly? Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/741632/edit) your question to clarify instead of commenting.